# Unable to page refresh when I add window.addEventListener inside the component class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I have issues refreshing the page when I have `window.addEventListener` snippet in the component class.

```
componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener("keydown" , function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        if (event.keyCode === 13) {
            document.getElementById("searchLink").click();
        }
    });
}
```

**Note:** `ctrl+f5` doesn't work, all keyboard actions fail to work when I have this snippet enabled. even the chrome console is not opening with the keyboard shortcut. Refreshing the page with mouse pointer also doesn't work in the browser.

Comment: if needed more details, please let me know in comments - I will make adjustments in the question. I am really facing this issue

Comment: What issues are you experiencing?

Comment: @yuriy636 ctrl+f5 doesnt work, all keyboard actions fail to work when I have this snippet enabled. even the chrome console is not opening with the keyboard shortcut

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode
event.keycode is deprecated. You should be using event.code instead

Comment: @starborneNova I see that event.keyCode is deprecated but `event.code` is not working. Should I update any lib?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener("keydown" , function(event) {
        if (event.key === "Enter") {
            event.preventDefault();
            document.getElementById("searchLink").click();
        }
    });
}
```

preventDefault is canceling all keyboard key press